# Displaying the City and State using GMSAutocomplete - Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I have a GMSAutocompleteViewController that presents after a button is pressed. Heres the code:

```
 let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autocompleteController.delegate = self

    let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) |
        UInt(GMSPlaceField.placeID.rawValue))!
    autocompleteController.placeFields = fields

    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .geocode
    filter.country = "US"
    autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter

    present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The results from the view controller look like this when a user is searching:

[image]

and using this code, I can return the name of the place, as well as the formatted address and attributions:

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    print("Formatted address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
    print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Prints out->
Place Name: Tremosine
Formatted address: nil
Place attributions: nil

**What I want to return is the second line in the screenshot that says "Province of Brescia, Italy" so that I can store it on my backend. Any idea on how to get that text?**

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution for that issue and also I used singleton class for that.

```
class GoogleLocation {

    var lat, lng: Double?
    var city, state, country, name: String?

    func extractFromGooglePlcae(place: GMSPlace) -> GoogleLocation {
        self.lat = place.coordinate.latitude
        self.lng = place.coordinate.longitude
        self.city = place.name!
        self.state = place.addressComponents?.first(where: { $0.type == "administrative_area_level_1" })?.name
        self.country = place.addressComponents?.first(where: { $0.type == "country" })?.name
        self.name = self.getFullName()


        return self
    }

    private func getFullName() -> String {
        //return "\(String(describing: self.city)), \(String(describing: self.state)), \(String(describing: self.country))"
        return self.city! + ", " + self.state! + ", " + self.country!
    }
}
```

In the viewController you should pass place object.

```
 func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

          googleLocation = GoogleLocation().extractFromGooglePlcae(place: place)

        }
```

**Let me know if you have any issues regarding this.**
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use addressComponents value to get formatted address.

```
let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
autocompleteController.delegate = self
let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: 
  UInt(GMSPlaceField.formattedAddress.rawValue) |
            UInt(GMSPlaceField.addressComponents.rawValue))!
autocompleteController.placeFields = fields

let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = .geocode
filter.country = "US"
autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter

present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```